# Is there any way to run another cell of R code which depends on current python flask app cell's input by user in google-colaboratory?

Tags: python, r, flask, google-colaboratory, rpy2

I am running a flask app in google colab using **flask_ngrok** and in that I am asking user to upload a .pssm file.
Now I want to run a R package at same time as it depends on file uploaded by user, along with app cell running (basically I want to jump back and forth to cells without affecting current cell which is running my app).

I'm using `%load_ext rpy2.ipython` to use R and Python in one notebook.
I have seen some multithreading packages like **parsl**  but problem is that I want R cell not Python cell.

Or Is there any other way to this problem like making request to another colab notebook and getting response in current notebook (getting a Response : **csv file**, Request with a: **input file**).

Is it possible technically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem like this:

```
filenm=""
```

```
%%R -i filenm -o fun1
f1<-function(filenm)
{
  d1<-NULL
  d1<-rbind(d1,some_function(filenm))
  write.csv(d1,file="/content/t1.csv")  
}
```

Here -i is used for passing input variable from python to R in our case "filenm" and -o is used to pass the output variable from R to python in our case we get fun1 as output in python
Now that R function is converted into python so that we can use it like this:

```
fun1(filenm)  #in Python shell
```

Hope this helps